# c# mysql connect mistake

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

```
MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("SERVER=http://185.106.208.... ;DATABASE=netcom_demo;UID=root;PASSWORD=test123;");
```

ı take "unable connect to any of the specified MySql Host" 
what can ı do?

Comment: Contact your IT support to ensure host exists?  Not much we can do with this question

Comment: can not do anything?

Comment: Add a port to the string? Default is 3306 but it could have been changed. But if the site is hosted, as Twelfth mentioned, check with the ISP first.

Comment: ı chech port .it is 3306

Comment: A connection string for a MySQL server containing http:// ? That looks pretty fishy.

Comment: Can you ping that IP?

Answer (score 1):

The First thing you should do is to check connectivity to the database you can use a tool like Workbench to connect to the database. Also check you can ping the IP address, If you can't connect using a client like Workbench maybe the problem could be a firewall.

Answer (score 0):

This Will help you.

```
MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("User ID=root;pwd=test123;Initial Catalog=netcom_demo;Data Source=185.106.208....;");
```